# How to populate google map with multiple markers from JPA database

Tags: google-maps, jsf, google-maps-markers

I have a JPA data object from a table that includes longitude, latitude, location name among other data. I need to display multiple google map markers on a JSF webpage. I will be very grateful for a solution, a working sample will be very nice. Alternatively, a JSF managed bean method sample to help me solve this will be good.

Comment: 1) What have you tried? What is the **concrete** issue you are having?

Comment: 2) Do not mix questions: It is a question about JPA? About JSF? About Google Maps?

Answer (score 0):

YOu could read them into in a array and then use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example). But there is a better demo [here](http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples/home.jsf) (JSF) and [here](http://biemond.blogspot.ie/2008/09/google-maps-for-jsf-gmaps4jsf-in.html)
this blog deals with jpa https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/mashup_explanation_part_i

also i found a very good [code sample for jsf](http://cuppajavamattiz.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/708/)